# Why are positions of an array being stored in a DB while using Slick

Tags: arrays, postgresql, scala, slick

I'm working on a Scala project using Slick and postgres. In one of our tables we have a bigint array, which is initialised as empty.
While using Slick to update that array we noticed that when checking the table, this is now appearing next to the values of the array: [X:Y]={...}

[positional values in DB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GgZYi.png)

After some investigation these values seem to be the position of the last added value. As adding values to the array updates these values as well.
The problem is, this only happens if the array is updated using slick, but not using sql directly. Using sql still updates the position but adding a value to an array that doesn't have the position doesn't add the position.

To update array we are using the slick update function and updating the entire array after appending the new value to the former one.

Why does this happen? And are there any repercussions?

Comment: We need more details here. What is the type of the column in the db? What is the type in Slick? What is the type the whatever data model you are using? As a wild speculation, if the first two questions are char/text and String is that you appending a "toString" representation of you data model.

Comment: in the db it's a bigint[], it's specified, in slick it's just a List[Long]

Comment: Ah, I see, it's a postgres array column. I've never interacted with these through Slick. A few recommendations: add more context to the question so people can help you, if you are new to scala, slick and/or postgres, I understand that figuring out "the right context" can be quite hard. You can also try looking at https://github.com/tminglei/slick-pg, a few Slick extensions to help interacting with postgresql.